# Node MySQL Connection Not Working

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am new to Node an Express, I have this code which simply connects to a MySQL Db...Nothing is happening when I try to 127.0.0.1:9080. I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what...nothing in the console no errors, tried in chrome, FF, Safari and IE...Any ideas.

```
var http = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var hbs = require('hbs'); 
var path = require('path');
var mysql = require('mysql');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);
//mysql connect
var connection = mysql.createConnection({  
  host : 'mysql://root@localhost/mydb2',
  user : 'someone',
  password : 'secret'
  });

app.get('/', function(request, response) { 
 connection.query('select * from sometable', function(err, rows){
     if (err) throw err;
 console.log("Test01=" + row[0].toString());
}); 

app.listen(9080);
});
```

Comment: `console.log` outputs to node's console, not the browser's one!

Comment: what do you mean by nothing happens when you go to 127.0.0.1:9080?  Does express even serve the page or is it not finding the server or what?

Comment: By saying you've tested this in all these browsers you're not saying you're running it in the browser, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something in the response to see it on the browser.

Add this line before `console.log()` statement.

```
response.json(rows);
```